# After neo4j-admin import going Ok I can't see any nodes

Tags: browser, import, neo4j

I have a neo4j inside a docker container, and i'm trying to import a huge csv into neo4j, as doing it with LOAD CSV is really slow, I've tried this other way that seems to go faster.

`bin/neo4j-admin import --mode csv --nodes:Clicks import/data.csv`

On the browser at http://localhost:17474/browser/ before doing the import I can see Size: 0 and after the import I see Size: 329,56MiB, so it seems the data is there, but no nodes are shown on the browser and I don't know why.

Here is the result of the import:

`IMPORT DONE in 10s 731ms.
Imported:
  631222 nodes
  0 relationships
  8899091 properties
Peak memory usage: 780.23 MB`

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Maria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. It seems that after using `neo4j-admin import` it's necessary to restart the neo4j service, but doing a `neo4j restart` inside the docker container doesn't work properly, so you need to stop the docker container and start it again, when you do so, the nodes appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem, just because I didn't understand very well the command itself :P.

Having in account that you have the correct format of csv files (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets), and running neo4j using docker (https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/). After executing inside container:

```
bin/neo4j-import \
--into /data/databases/graph.db \
--id-type string \
--nodes:Airport /var/lib/neo4j/import/airports.csv \
--relationships:connections /var/lib/neo4j/import/connections.csv
```

You can restart the docker container, and then see new dataset in current database. `--into /data/databases/graph.db` points to the database where neo4j-import will save dataset, and if current neo4j database instance doesn't point to this, wont show new dataset. `/data/databases/graph.db` is the default database.

Answer (score -1):

The neo4j browser visualization shows the results of Cypher queries. You probably did not enter a query.

Try this query, which should show 20 nodes:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n
LIMIT 20;
```

[Here is a guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) that shows you how to use the browser.

Comment: Hi! I've tried this query and returns `(no changes, no records)`

Comment: Do you have multiple DB's running locally? It looks like the browser service at `http://localhost:17474/browser/` is for an empty DB. And port `17474` is not a default neo4j [connector port](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/configuration/connectors/#connectors). Does port `7474` work? If so, then there is a second DB on the same machine.